# Не отображаются хлебные крошки на 1-м уровне

Tags: php, веб-программирование, битрикс, breadcrumbs

Есть компонент news

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("title", "Каталог для поисковиков");
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Каталог");
?>
    <!--
    <section>
        <div class="bread_crumbs_bl">
            <div class="standart_width">
                <ul class="bread_crumbs not_style">
                    <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                        "bitrix:breadcrumb",
                        "",
                        Array(
                            "PATH" => "",
                            "SITE_ID" => "s1",
                            "START_FROM" => "0"
                        )
                    );?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    -->
    <section>
        <div class="white_bg">
            <div class="standart_width">
                <div class="title">
                    <?$APPLICATION->ShowTitle(false);?>
                </div>                              
                <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:news", 
    "catalog", 
    array(
        "ADD_ELEMENT_CHAIN" => "Y",
        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "Y",
        "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
        "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
        "BROWSER_TITLE" => "-",
        "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "CHECK_DATES" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
        "DETAIL_DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
        "DETAIL_FIELD_CODE" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "DETAIL_PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_PAGER_TEMPLATE" => "",
        "DETAIL_PAGER_TITLE" => "Страница",
        "DETAIL_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
            0 => "ACTION",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "DETAIL_SET_CANONICAL_URL" => "N",
        "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "N",
        "DISPLAY_DATE" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_NAME" => "N",
        "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
        "FILE_404" => "",
        "HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => "N",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "10",
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "catalog_goods",
        "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "N",
        "LIST_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
        "LIST_FIELD_CODE" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "LIST_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
            0 => "ACTION",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "MESSAGE_404" => "",
        "META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
        "META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
        "NEWS_COUNT" => "10",
        "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
        "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
        "PAGER_TITLE" => "Каталог товаров",
        "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => "",
        "SEF_FOLDER" => "/catalog_goods/",
        "SEF_MODE" => "Y",
        "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "N",
        "SET_STATUS_404" => "Y",
        "SET_TITLE" => "N",
        "SHOW_404" => "Y",
        "SORT_BY1" => "ID",
        "SORT_BY2" => "SORT",
        "SORT_ORDER1" => "ASC",
        "SORT_ORDER2" => "ASC",
        "STRICT_SECTION_CHECK" => "N",
        "USE_CATEGORIES" => "N",
        "USE_FILTER" => "N",
        "USE_PERMISSIONS" => "N",
        "USE_RATING" => "N",
        "USE_REVIEW" => "N",
        "USE_RSS" => "N",
        "USE_SEARCH" => "N",
        "USE_SHARE" => "N",
        "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "catalog",
        "SEF_URL_TEMPLATES" => array(
            "news" => "",
            "section" => "#SECTION_CODE#/",
            "detail" => "#SECTION_CODE#/#ELEMENT_CODE#/",
        )
    ),
    false
);?>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>
```

В нем отображается список разделов (файл news.php - `C:\OpenServer\domains\mytechnoshop.ru\local\templates\main\components\bitrix\news\catalog\news.php`)

```html
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
/** @var array $arParams */
/** @var array $arResult */
/** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
/** @global CUser $USER */
/** @global CDatabase $DB */
/** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
/** @var string $templateName */
/** @var string $templateFile */
/** @var string $templateFolder */
/** @var string $componentPath */
/** @var CBitrixComponent $component */
$this->setFrameMode(true);
?>

<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:catalog.section.list",
    "catalog",
    Array(
        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "Y",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => $arParams["CACHE_TYPE"],
        "CACHE_TIME" => $arParams["CACHE_TIME"],
        "CACHE_FILTER" => $arParams["CACHE_FILTER"],
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => $arParams["CACHE_GROUPS"],
        "COUNT_ELEMENTS" => "N",
        "COUNT_ELEMENTS_FILTER" => "CNT_ACTIVE",
        "CUSTOM_SECTION_SORT" => ["ID" => "ASC"],       
        "FILTER_NAME" => "sectionsFilter",
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => $arParams["IBLOCK_TYPE"],
        "IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
        "SECTION_CODE" => "",
        "SECTION_FIELDS" => array("", ""),
        "SECTION_ID" => $_REQUEST["SECTION_ID"],
        "SECTION_URL" => "",
        "SECTION_USER_FIELDS" => array("", ""),
        "SHOW_PARENT_NAME" => "Y",
        "TOP_DEPTH" => "1",
        "VIEW_MODE" => "TILE"       
    ),
    $component
);?>
```

При щелчке на одном из разделов в Каталог (к примеру, на Телевизоры, Видео, Аудио) отображается список подразделов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Назовем этот уровень - подуровень №2.

При щелчке на одном из разделов в Телевизоры, Видео, Аудио (к примеру, на Телевизоры) отображается список телевизоров с помощью компонента news.list

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Назовем этот уровень - подуровень №3.

Подуровни №2 и №3 отображаются с помощью файла section.php - `C:\OpenServer\domains\mytechnoshop.ru\local\templates\main\components\bitrix\news\catalog\section.php`

```html
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
/** @var array $arParams */
/** @var array $arResult */
/** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
/** @global CUser $USER */
/** @global CDatabase $DB */
/** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
/** @var string $templateName */
/** @var string $templateFile */
/** @var string $templateFolder */
/** @var string $componentPath */
/** @var CBitrixComponent $component */
$this->setFrameMode(true);
?>
<?
    if (CModule::IncludeModule('iblock')) {
        $arSection=CIBlockSection::GetList(['LEFT_MARGIN' => 'ASC'], ['IBLOCK_ID' => $arParams['IBLOCK_ID'], 'ACTIVE' => 'Y', 'CODE' => $arResult['VARIABLES']['SECTION_CODE']])->fetch();
        $dbS=CIBlockSection::GetList(['LEFT_MARGIN' => 'ASC'], ['IBLOCK_ID' => $arParams['IBLOCK_ID'], 'ACTIVE' => 'Y', 'SECTION_ID' => $arSection['ID']]);
        $countS=$dbS->SelectedRowsCount();  
    }
?>


<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:catalog.section.list",
    "catalog",
    Array(
        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "N",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => $arParams["CACHE_TYPE"],
        "CACHE_TIME" => $arParams["CACHE_TIME"],
        "CACHE_FILTER" => $arParams["CACHE_FILTER"],
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => $arParams["CACHE_GROUPS"],
        "COUNT_ELEMENTS" => "N",
        "COUNT_ELEMENTS_FILTER" => "CNT_ACTIVE",
        "CUSTOM_SECTION_SORT" => ["ID" => "ASC"],
        "FILTER_NAME" => "sectionsFilter",
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => $arParams["IBLOCK_TYPE"],
        "IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
        "SECTION_CODE" => $arResult["VARIABLES"]["SECTION_CODE"],
        "SECTION_FIELDS" => array("", ""),
        "SECTION_ID" => $_REQUEST["SECTION_ID"],
        "SECTION_URL" => "",
        "SECTION_USER_FIELDS" => array("", ""),
        "SHOW_PARENT_NAME" => "Y",
        "TOP_DEPTH" => "2",
        "VIEW_MODE" => "TILE"       
    ),
    $component
);?>


<?if (!$countS):?>

        <div class="catalog_banner">
            <a href=""><img src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/img/catalog_banner.png" alt=""/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="content clear_after">
            <div class="content_l">
                <div class="filter_bl">
                    <img src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/img/filter.png" alt=""/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content_c">
                <div class="sorting_bl">
                    <span>Сортировать:</span>
                    <a class="sorting_el active min" href=""><i></i>По цене</a>
                    <a class="sorting_el active max" href=""><i></i>По рейтингу</a>
                    <a class="sorting_el" href=""><i></i>По новизне</a>
                </div>


<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:news.list",
    "cataloginsection",
    Array(
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => $arParams["IBLOCK_TYPE"],
        "IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
        "NEWS_COUNT" => $arParams["NEWS_COUNT"],
        "SORT_BY1" => $arParams["SORT_BY1"],
        "SORT_ORDER1" => $arParams["SORT_ORDER1"],
        "SORT_BY2" => $arParams["SORT_BY2"],
        "SORT_ORDER2" => $arParams["SORT_ORDER2"],
        "FIELD_CODE" => $arParams["LIST_FIELD_CODE"],
        "PROPERTY_CODE" => $arParams["LIST_PROPERTY_CODE"],
        "DETAIL_URL" => $arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["detail"],
        "SECTION_URL" => $arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["section"],
        "IBLOCK_URL" => $arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["news"],
        "DISPLAY_PANEL" => $arParams["DISPLAY_PANEL"],
        "SET_TITLE" => $arParams["SET_TITLE"],
        "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => $arParams["SET_LAST_MODIFIED"],
        "MESSAGE_404" => $arParams["MESSAGE_404"],
        "SET_STATUS_404" => $arParams["SET_STATUS_404"],
        "SHOW_404" => $arParams["SHOW_404"],
        "FILE_404" => $arParams["FILE_404"],
        "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => $arParams["INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN"],
        "CACHE_TYPE" => $arParams["CACHE_TYPE"],
        "CACHE_TIME" => $arParams["CACHE_TIME"],
        "CACHE_FILTER" => $arParams["CACHE_FILTER"],
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => $arParams["CACHE_GROUPS"],
        "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => $arParams["DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER"],
        "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => $arParams["DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER"],
        "PAGER_TITLE" => $arParams["PAGER_TITLE"],
        "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => $arParams["PAGER_TEMPLATE"],
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => $arParams["PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS"],
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => $arParams["PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING"],
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => $arParams["PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME"],
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => $arParams["PAGER_SHOW_ALL"],
        "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => $arParams["PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE"],
        "PAGER_BASE_LINK" => $arParams["PAGER_BASE_LINK"],
        "PAGER_PARAMS_NAME" => $arParams["PAGER_PARAMS_NAME"],
        "DISPLAY_DATE" => $arParams["DISPLAY_DATE"],
        "DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => $arParams["DISPLAY_PICTURE"],
        "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => $arParams["DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT"],
        "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => $arParams["PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN"],
        "ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => $arParams["LIST_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT"],
        "USE_PERMISSIONS" => $arParams["USE_PERMISSIONS"],
        "GROUP_PERMISSIONS" => $arParams["GROUP_PERMISSIONS"],
        "FILTER_NAME" => $arParams["FILTER_NAME"],
        "HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => $arParams["HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL"],
        "CHECK_DATES" => $arParams["CHECK_DATES"],
        "PARENT_SECTION" => "",
        "PARENT_SECTION_CODE" => $arResult["VARIABLES"]["SECTION_CODE"],        
    ),
    $component
);?>

</div>
</div>

<?endif;?>
```

Но в результате хлебные крошки на первом уровне не отображаются (на всех остальных нормально).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как добиться отображения хлебных крошек на всех уровнях?

Comment: Так отобраюжаются же. Где проблема то?
"Главная > Каталог"  
это нормальная Крошка на 1 уровне в разделе Каталог

Comment: необходимо, чтобы было "Главная > Каталог > Телевизоры, Видео, Аудио" (последний скриншот)

Comment: Судя по всему, за хлебные крошки в вашей конфигурации отвечает компонент bitrix:news.list в файле C:\OpenServer\domains\mytechnoshop.ru\local\templates\main\components\bitrix\news\catalog\section.php. Но поскольку на первом уровне он отключён, то и хлебных крошек нет.

Comment: @ВикторКарев как добиться правильного отображения хлебных крошек? Как изменить мои файлы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно в sections.php разрешить компоненту bitrix:catalog.section.list добавлять хлебные крошки, если есть подразделы.

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:catalog.section.list",
    "catalog",
    Array(
        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => $countS ? "Y" : "N",
```

Comment: спасибо преогромнейшее, помогло.